# Kubuntu 15.04 File Open Dialog is not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Once I try to open file in some editor or project in IDE, for instance file in Kate or project in QtCreator, the File open dialog shows up, but whatever location I click (home, root, mounted disks, ...), there are no files to select. The situation is logged in terminal with following error/warn:

```
URL cannot be listed
trash:/"
couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:
klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'file'.
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem with **installing kde package** `kio` using command:

```
sudo apt-get install kio
```

and now everything works fine!